# Laravel 5: "Trying to get property of non-object" when getting data from 2 linked models

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a simple Laravel 5 app for testing purposes and I'm still struggling with displaying the desired data through models relationships.
Everything works fine when I test models relationships through artisan tinker.
In my index view, everything is fine... until I use a second linked model, which gives me the error in the subject.

Here are my tables (migrations):

```
Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('status');
});

Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('sn');
});

Schema::create('services', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('type');
});
```

Here are my 3 models:

//File: App\Order.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model {

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
    }
}
```

//File: App\Product.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

//File: App\Service.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service extends Model {

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

//My simple controller OrdersController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::all();
    return view('orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

And finally my view "/resources/views/orders/index.blade.php"

```
<ul>
    @foreach( $orders as $order )
        <li>
            Order# {{ $order->id }} -             //this line is OK
            {{$order->products->first()->name}} - //this line is OK 
            {{$order->services->first()->name}} - //as soon as I add this line, I get the error! 
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

=> Am I doing something wrong? Isn't it possible to retrieve data from 2 "external" models within the same view?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does every order have at least one service assigned? My guess is not, in which case you should wrap it in an if statement:

```
@foreach( $dossiers as $dossier )
    <li>
    Order# {{ $order->id }}
    @if($product = $order->products->first())
        {{ $product->name }}
    @endif
    @if($service = $order->services->first())
        {{ $service->name }}
    @endif
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks a lot lukasgeiter! I didn't know that... It works! But it is quite heavy to create an if loop to test existence of each value before echoing it! Is there any other "general" way to avoid this loop each time? Thanks!