# laravel get last related model

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
class Keyword extends Model {

    public function results()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Result');
    }
}

class Result extends Model {

    public function keywords()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Keyword');
    }   
}
```

these are my classes, but when i access

```
$keyword->results->where('engine','Google')->last()->created_at
```

I get error : Trying to get property of non-object

if I `var_dump($keyword->results->where('engine','Google')->last())`, it show object of Result class

So what I am doing wrong here? i need to filter results that is working fine, but can't access properties/attributes of result

Comment: can you show the result of the var_dump()?

Comment: Result :var_dump($keyword->results->where('engine','Google')->last()) object(App\Result)[332]
  protected 'table' => string 'results' (length=7)
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'deleted_at' (length=10)
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'position' (length=8)
      1 => string 'engine' (length=6)
      2 => string 'date' (length=4)
      3 => string 'keyword_id' (length=10)
  protected 'connection' => null
  ......

Comment: try the following one and post the result  var_dump($keyword->results()->where('engine','Google')->last()->toArray())

Comment: @varathanyajiv thanks for your help, but problem was solved see my solution and the error that I was making

Answer (score 1):

I was accessing results for all keyewords in loop even if there was no related result, I did like

@if($ranking = $keyword->results->where('engine',$engine)->last())

{!! $ranking->created_at !!}

@endif

and the issue is solved, got help from : [Laravel 5: “Trying to get property of non-object”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348513/laravel-5-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-when-getting-data-from-2-linke)